# Updating d3 bar chart labels with new data of variable length

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, bar-chart

I am drawing a simple bar chart with labels using d3 and want to be able to update the chart with new data that may have more or less items than the existing chart. I know I need to use enter/update/exit but I am having trouble with the selection and getting the update working correctly. I have the bar and labels grouped together and when I try to update, I keep adding another bar to the group instead of updating it.

I am updating with this function:

```
function updateChart(){
x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.count; })]);
chart = d3.select('.chart');

bar = chart.selectAll('g')
        .data(data);

// Enter…
bar.enter().append('g')
    .attr('transform', function(d, i) { return 'translate(0,' + (i * (barHeight+barMargin)) + ')'; });

bar.append('rect')
    .attr("x", labelW)
    .attr("height", barHeight)
    .attr('width', 0)
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr('width', function(d) { return x(d.count); });

// Update…
bar.transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr('width', function(d) { return x(d.count); });

// Exit…
bar.exit()
    .remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a couple of things:

- in your update function, it should be `newData`, not `data`;
- set the value to `barMargin`;
- added the `bar.text` to the update function.

But the most important was providing a key to the data, like this:

```
.data(newData, function(d){ return d.value});
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/fybLrujp/2/

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the kiwi... give me some minutes

Comment: Done, check the new fiddle (edited answer). But listen, this is just to show you how it's done, your code right now has several issues. If, for instance, you click "update" several times, you'll see that it adds new text elements, that pile up.

Comment: The first g element has 2 sets of bars because of the same problem with the texts. Actually, if you click update several times, you'll have several sets of bars. I just made a new fiddle (again!) removing this problem, please check.